# Failed to load ApplicationContext in my Test (Junit with Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have a problem... Well, when I start my test, I throw me the following error, and can not find that he is doing wrong. Agrege corresponding to the "Application-context" where is the notation hibernate settings, but I can not perform my test successfully

**"WebAppInitializer":**

```
package com.checkwork.conf;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("Initializing web application with context configuration class {}", WebAppConfigurer.class.getCanonicalName());

        //WebApplication Param-Value (Web.XML)
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webAppContext.register(WebAppConfigurer.class);

        //Crea Servlet y mapea las peticiones con "/" sin extensiones.
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(webAppContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

**"WebAppConfigurer":**

```
package com.checkwork.conf;

import com.checkwork.model.Empleado;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement /** Gestor de transacciones que permiten habilitar los componentes para la conexion a la BD */
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.checkwork"})
public class WebAppConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/module");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");     
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(Empleado.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /** 
     * Agrega al Caché la librería OpenUI5 en tiempo de ejecución {WEB-INF/lib}
    */

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/", "/resources/**")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }


}
```

**Test:**

```
package com.checkwork.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import com.checkwork.conf.WebAppConfigurer;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebAppConfigurer.class)
public class EmpleadoServiceTest {

    private EmpleadoService empleadoService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        empleadoService = new EmpleadoService();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getAllTest(){
        assertNotNull(empleadoService.getAll());
    }
}
```

**Error console - Junit:**

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1761de10] to prepare test instance [com.checkwork.service.EmpleadoServiceTest@22df874e]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebAppConfigurer.class)`

to
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebAppConfigurer.class, initializers=WebAppInitializer.class)`

**update**

Also include `@WebIntegrationTest` below `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: By placing initializers = WebAppInitializer.class gives me an error but does not indicate that error is: /